# process highly efficient queries - polars

Tags: python-polars

I need to increase performance to apply this query in polars.

```
def condition(avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val):
    return (
            (pl.col(f'avg{avg_1_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_1_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_2_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_2_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_3_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_3_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_4_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_4_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
    )

# Define values
avg_1_vals = range(2, 20)
avg_2_vals = range(3, 30, 3)
avg_3_vals = range(7, 70, 4)
avg_4_vals = range(5, 50, 5)
std_vals = [1, 2, 3]

# Elab condition
df = df.with_columns(
    [
        condition(avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val)
        .alias(f'en_{avg_1_val}_{avg_2_val}_{avg_3_val}_{avg_4_val}_{std_val}')

        for avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val
        in itertools.product(avg_1_vals, avg_2_vals, avg_3_vals, avg_4_vals, std_vals)
    ]
)
Total time taken: 0:00:18.419206
```

In special, i'd like use all machine computing power cos it seems being signle core process.

I tried with this code, but looks pretty slow:

```
import itertools
import random
from datetime import datetime

import polars as pl

"""
Dynamic condition elaboration
"""

# Example data
serie = [random.randint(2, 10) for x in range(100_000)]
df = pl.LazyFrame(dict(data=serie))
column_name = 'data'


def avg_builder(avg_val, std_val: list) -> pl.Expr:
    avg_columns = (
        pl.col(column_name).rolling_mean(window_size=avg_val).rolling_std(std_val).alias(f'avg{avg_val}_std{std_val}'))
    return avg_columns


# Define in-out rule
def condition(avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val):
    return (
            (pl.col(f'avg{avg_1_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_1_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_2_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_2_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_3_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_3_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
            & (pl.col(f'avg{avg_4_val}_std{std_val}') > pl.col(f'avg{avg_4_val}_std{std_val}').shift(1))
    )


# Define values
avg_1_vals = range(2, 20)
avg_2_vals = range(3, 30, 3)
avg_3_vals = range(7, 70, 4)
avg_4_vals = range(5, 50, 5)
std_vals = [1, 2, 3]

print("Total combinations:", len(avg_1_vals) * len(avg_2_vals) * len(avg_3_vals) * len(avg_4_vals) * len(std_vals))

# Get averages single values
avg_vals = set(list(avg_1_vals) + list(avg_2_vals) + list(avg_3_vals) + list(avg_4_vals))

# Get averages single values
std_vals = list(std_vals)

startAt = datetime.utcnow()
# Elab columns
df = df.with_columns(
    [avg_builder(avg_val, std_val) for avg_val, std_val in itertools.product(avg_vals, std_vals)]
)

# Elab condition
df = df.with_columns(
    [
        condition(avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val)
        .alias(f'en_{avg_1_val}_{avg_2_val}_{avg_3_val}_{avg_4_val}_{std_val}')

        for avg_1_val, avg_2_val, avg_3_val, avg_4_val, std_val
        in itertools.product(avg_1_vals, avg_2_vals, avg_3_vals, avg_4_vals, std_vals)
    ]
)

df = df.collect()
print(df.tail())
print("Total time taken:", datetime.utcnow() - startAt)
```

I tried to see timing of itertools, of query building... but the bottleneck is still in apply condition. Addly, i have several dataframes to analyze with dynamic conditions so it comes really time consuming

Comment: When `.collect()` runs I see all CPU cores maxed out for ~1.5 seconds but then it seems to fall back to using a single core. This probably needs to be debugged as a performance issue by the devs e.g. on [Discord](https://discord.gg/4UfP5cfBE7) / [GitHub](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues)